# parse HTMLElmentObject with innerHTML in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a cat clicker game. Where I Have five cat and each one has click function which increase count on every click.

I have created a DOM from javascript function, I have create image from `document.create` method so that I can attached event to it. So my javascript code contains both pure HTML and HTMLElementObj. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2b28pyg/).

But innerHTML is not paring the element which is creating by the `document.createElement`

```
function fac(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.count = 0;
}

var cats = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5']

function $(name) {
  return document.querySelector(name);
}
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
  var cat = new fac(cats[i])
  html += "<div>";
  html += "<div>" + cat.name + "</div>";
  var elem = document.createElement('img');
  elem.src = 'https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1126/625069434_db86b67df8_n.jpg';
  html += elem;
  html += "<div class='count " + i + "'></div>";
  html += "</div>";
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $('.count' + i).innerText = ++cat.count;
  }, false);
  $('#getClicked').innerHTML = html

}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code, or even a question here ?

Comment: You can't add an element, which is really an object, to a HTML string, you would have to use `appendChild` or similar methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing strings and dom elements and that won't work. Just do everything as strings

```
 html += "<div>";
  html += "<div>" + cat.name + "</div>";
  var elem = "<img src='https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1126/625069434_db86b67df8_n.jpg'>";
  html += elem;
  html += "<div class='count " + i + "'></div>";
```

or as dom elements (a bit more learning needed to start with but better in the long run)

Comment: So how to bind event on fly on html strings